# Android LiveData Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I've got the following ViewModel:

```
class FundamentalsViewModel: ViewModel() {
    var fundamentalsLiveData = MutableLiveData<WrappedResult<DataResponse>>()
    private val repository = FundamentalsRespository()
    private var job: Job? = null

    fun getData(type: String) {
        if(job == null || job?.isActive == false) {
            fundamentalsLiveData.value = WrappedResult.Loading
            job = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                try {
                    val response = repository.getData(type)
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        fundamentalsLiveData.value = WrappedResult.Success(response)
                    }
                } catch(e: Exception) {
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        fundamentalsLiveData.value = WrappedResult.Failure(e)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works perfectly in-house, but out in the field I'm getting Crashylitics reports that say this:
"Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.j0.d.u.p, parameter symbol"
on the line that is:

```
fundamentalsLiveData.value = WrappedResult.Loading
```

There is no other information in the crash log. How is it possible that there is any NPE here? The WrappedResult is a typical Kotlin sealed class that looks like this:

```
sealed class WrappedResult<out T> {
    data class Success<out T: Any>(val data:T) : WrappedResult<T>()
    data class Failure(val error: Throwable) : WrappedResult<Nothing>()
    data class CallFailure(val error: String) : WrappedResult<Nothing>()
    object Loading : WrappedResult<Nothing>()
}
```

Comment: Could it be a problem of declaration/init for object Loading in WrappedResult?

Comment: I considered that, however if that's the case I don't know how to fix the problem. Also, I've test just explicitly setting fundamentalsLiveData.value = null and I don't get a crash.

Comment: I think that this would only suggest that the problem really regards the Loading object, i've never programmed in Kotlin, just wondering around. But i think that's the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and it had to do with the fragment having setRetainInstance(false). If the activity was killed on a task out, this happened coming back in. I haven't yet been able to fully understand how why this would happen since the view model was created with the fragment's scope, but changing to setRetainInstance(true) stopped the crash.